# Relation between expected values of eigenvalues of Laplacian matrix of a graph and eigenvalues of expected Laplacian matrix of that graph?

Tags: co.combinatorics, random-graphs, laplacian

Particularly, I am dealing with Erdős–Rényi random (,), so the expected Laplacian matrix of (,) is (−), where  and  are one and identity matrices, respectively.

In addition,if the distribution (unsure, but might be power law) of the eigenvalues of Laplacian matrix of the graph (,) is known, then it seems to me that expected value of the eigenvalues has some closed form formula depending on  and  in the asymptotic case.

Answer (score 1):

See the papers by Erdos (no relation) and collaborators, e.g.:

*Erdős, László; Knowles, Antti; Yau, Horng-Tzer; Yin, Jun*, [**Spectral statistics of Erdős-Rényi graphs. I: Local semicircle law**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1214/11-AOP734), Ann. Probab. 41, No. 3B, 2279-2375 (2013). [ZBL1272.05111](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1272.05111).

*Erdős, László; Knowles, Antti; Yau, Horng-Tzer; Yin, Jun*, [**Spectral statistics of Erdős-Rényi graphs II: eigenvalue spacing and the extreme eigenvalues**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00220-012-1527-7), Commun. Math. Phys. 314, No. 3, 587-640 (2012). [ZBL1251.05162](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1251.05162).